# Run bash script on millions of csv files

Tags: bash, sed, cygwin

I am trying to run below `bash` script on more than 1 million of `csv` file:

```
#!/bin/bash
new_header="cell,id,too,issue,valid,DPT,RH,TMP,U,V"
sed -i'' "1s/.*/$new_header/" /cygdrive/d/csv/*.csv
```

But while running this code I am getting the following error:

```
./bash.sh: line 3: 11464 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) sed -i'' "1s/.*/$new_header/" /cygdrive/d/csv/*.csv
```

I am sure there is some way to run script on 1 million `csv` files, but I haven't found anything yet.

Answer (score 5):

I guess that the length of the command line generated by expanding `/cygdrive/d/csv/*.csv` is too long.

One way to get around this would be by using `find`:

```
find /cygdrive/d/csv/ -name '*.csv' -exec sed -i '' "1s/.*/$new_header/" {} +
```

This runs the minimum number of separate sed processes required, keeping the command length within the limit.

As mentioned in the comments, if your version of sed actually needs an argument passing after `-i` (GNU sed doesn't), then you need a space before `''`. Otherwise you can just remove `''`.

Comment: `sed -i''` is same as `sed -i`.  If we really intend to pass a null argument to `-i`, we should invoke it as `sed -i ''`.

Comment: @TomFenech, When I am running this this code on just 200 files it's working fine but when I ran this code on the directory which contains 1 million `csv` files. It's not working. Any comments?

Comment: @TomFenech, Now it's not throwing this error `./bash.sh: line 3: 11464 Segmentation fault      (core dumped)`. It's running though but not renaming the first line.

Comment: @TomFenech, it's just running without throwing the above error. But when I checked ten random `csv` files just to confirm that whether it's renaming the first line or not. Its not renaming it.

Comment: I mean remove -exec and everything after it

Comment: @TomFenech, oh my bad. Apologies. I did it. It prints the csv files but these files does not contain the updated headers.

Comment: @TomFenech, Is there any way that I can use `for loop` to iterate just on first 100,000 csv files and parallel I can run one more bash script which will perform operations on csv files ranging from 100,001 to 200,000? Because current bash script is taking so long.

Comment: There are ways to parallelise what you're trying to do but I think that opening and closing so many files and creating all the temporary backup files is ẃhat's making it slow, and that's a limitation that you can't really get around when everything's on the same file system/disk.

Answer (score 1):

Well done on getting the `Segmentation Fault`  that shouldn't actually happen.

I would use a `find` here (or possibly `xargs`).  It can break up the result into many calls and never do anything with 1,000,000 args

`find` has an `-exec` switch which allows it to execute a command with the files it finds instead of simply printing.

Comment: Thanks! But I am using bash script first time.. I don't know how this  `find` works. Could you please tell in code? I really appreciate your efforts.

Comment: I think Tom Fenech may have already done so in his answer.  FYI, on the command line you should be able to call `man find` for the manual.  Also google "linux man find" should come up with the same manual on the web.